# How to set up Transcend StoreJet 25M3 1TB USB 3.0 external hard drive to backup an ext4 file system?

Tags: mount, permissions, hard-drive, format

I just bought me a [Transcend StoreJet 25M3 1TB USB 3.0 external hard drive](http://www.custompcreview.com/reviews/transcend-storejet-m3-1tb-usb-3-external-hard-drive-review/17949/) to back up data from my laptop running Ubuntu 14.10. I tried unison file synchronizer, but I got errors

> Failed to set permissions of file
>   /media/hakon/Transcend/.unison..bash_profile.b54585281d82effb5afc6d1bfff73346.unison.tmp
>   to rw-rw-r--: the permissions was set to rw------- instead. The
>   filesystem probably does not support all permission bits. If this is a
>   FAT filesystem, you should set the "fat" option to true. Otherwise,
>   you should probably set the "perms" option to 0o1713 (or to 0 if you
>   don't need to synchronize permissions)

The file system on the external drive is of type `fuseblk` and the file system on my laptop is `ext4`:

```
$ df -T /home/hakon
Filesystem     Type 1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      ext4 953333636 76460660 828423340   9% /

$ df -T /media/hakon/Transcend/
Filesystem     Type    1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1      fuseblk 976759996 135728 976624268   1% /media/hakon/Transcend
```

I guess the reason for the error message from `unison` is related to unsupported difference in permission bits for ext4 versus NTFS. But why does `unison` recommend setting `perms = 0o1713`? What does `0o1713` stand for?

After some googling, I wonder 
what would be the recommended way for me to proceed :

- convert the file system on the external drive to `ext4`, using for example `mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc1`, or
- try to modify the settings in the `unison` profile, using, for example `perms = 0o1713` ?

Comment: Use the built in backup utility on the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to use `unison` since I have multiple machines that I need to synchronize with (`rsync` is a mirroring tool; `unison` is a synchronizer).. I also decided to reformat the external hard drive to use `ext4` file system:

```
sudo umount /media/hakon/Transcend
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc1

/dev/sdc1 contains a ntfs file system labelled 'Transcend'
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
Creating filesystem with 244190000 4k blocks and 61054976 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 0ddde628-b54a-4bb2-9823-b734fe0f78b9
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
    102400000, 214990848

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

Now I could run `unsion` with no problems:

```
sudo unison-gtk myprofile.prf
```

**Update**:

It turns out that after the reformatting, the harddrive will be owned by the `root` user. You should take back ownership of the drive to avoid a lot of trouble with file permissions in `unison`. Example:

```
sudo chown hakon:hakon -R /media/hakon/0ddde628-b54a-4bb2-9823-b734fe0f78b9/
```

Now, `unison` can also be run without `sudo`.

Comment: :( I formatted it and did not change ownership now my hard drive not working. How I can fix it? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @antindexer I am not sure I understand completely. Have you tried run the `chown` command I suggested?

Comment: I just formated my hard drive and pull out from system. When I connect it to another PC it stop working :(. Dose it related?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using the external drive on Windows computers, I would reformat it to ext4. You can either use the command you've cited or use the graphical frontend **GNOME Disks**, which is installed on Ubuntu by default.

For backups, I prefer **rsync**. The Arch wiki has [a great article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Full_system_backup_with_rsync) on how to do a full system backup with **rsync**.

Comment: Thanks for the help Eric, I decided to use `unison` and reformat the external drive to `ext4`.. see my answer below.